# Trying to make a useLocalStorage custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm fairly new to React

What i'm trying to achieve here is to is to make a custom hook and store data into localStorage but my hook doesn't seem to be working

here's the hook useLocalStorage

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
// import FeedbackData from '../data/FeedbackData'

export function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
    const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(() => {
        const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
        if (storedValue !== undefined || storedValue !== null) {
            return storedValue
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localValue))
    }, [localValue])

    return [localValue, setLocalValue]
}
```

here's how i'm using it in my context provider

```
    const [feedback, setFeedback] = useLocalStorage('tasks', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return storedValue !== null ? storedValue : initialValue
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localValue))
  }, [key, localValue])

  return [localValue, setLocalValue]
}
```

You should not check `storedValue` for `undefined` because localStorage returns `null` if the key does not exist. Also, you must add `key` to the dependencies array of `useEffect` hook.

And I think you might have forgotten to use `JSON.parse()` because localeStorage usually stores JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also probably do it like this:

```
 const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || initialValue);
```

Also, the code does not work because it should have been `&&` instead of `||`.

So instead of:

```
if (storedValue !== undefined || storedValue !== null) {
```

It should have been:

```
if (storedValue !== undefined && storedValue !== null) {
```

But the undefined is still useless so you can discard it. Just be mindful when using operators next time.